# java.awt.print only prints the first page

Tags: java, printing, pagination, graphics2d

i m trying to print a list according to the print example in oracle's web page and for some reason it would only print the first page of the list

i took the printing sample from oracle about basic printing :
[A Basic Printing Program](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html)

and modified it here to explain what i mean a little bit better

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class HelloWorldPrinter implements Printable, ActionListener {


    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                        PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        g.drawString("1.Hello world!", 100, 100);
        g.drawString("2.Hello world!", 100, 300);
        g.drawString("3.Hello world!", 100, 600);
        g.drawString("4.Hello world!", 100, 800);
        g.drawString("5.Hello world!", 100, 1000);
        g.drawString("6.Hello world!", 100, 1200);
        g.drawString("7.Hello world!", 100, 1500);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
         job.setPrintable(this);
         boolean ok = job.printDialog();
         if (ok) {
             try {
                  job.print();
             } catch (PrinterException ex) {
             }
         }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
        printButton.addActionListener(new HelloWorldPrinter());
        f.add("Center", printButton);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

this example would only print the first 4 lines ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for quite a while. [This example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/PaginationExample.java) helped me out a lot in getting it paginating properly. As was suggested in my question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217266/java-print-api-skipping-first-page), try copying in the tutorial example and make sure it works, then start adding your stuff one section at a time until it stops working, so you can see where the problem is.

Edit: Oops, didn't notice that the answer was from the OP. Oh, well, if anyone runs across this and OP's answer doesn't work, maybe mine will.