# Java Print API skipping first page

Tags: java, printing, pagination

I need some advice with the Java Print API. I have a program that goes through a Vector and prints each item on its own line. I'm trying to make it so when the line count reaches a certain number, it starts a new page. I've been looking at a [Java Tutorial example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/PaginationExample.java) to figure it out, but it's still not working. In debug mode, everything appears to be working properly, but for some reason it's printing the second page on the first sheet of paper and leaving the second sheet blank. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

EDIT: Here's the code for the print method:

```
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
        throws PrinterException {
    page = pageNum;
    Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
    paper.setSize(8.5 * 72, 11 * 72);
    paper.setImageableArea(0.5 * 72, 0.5 * 72, 7.5 * 72, 10 * 72);
    pf.setPaper(paper);

    if (page > pageTot) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
    if (cov) {
        g = drawCenteredString(dateS, 108, g, 56, Font.BOLD);
        g = drawCenteredString("Don Stewart Daily Fulfillment", 216, g, 38,
                Font.BOLD);
        g = drawCenteredString(((FileNode) ((TreePath) printPaths.get(j))
                .getPathComponent(((TreePath) printPaths.get(j))
                        .getPathCount() - 5)).toString(), 324, g, 64,
                Font.BOLD);
        g = drawCenteredString(((TreePath) printPaths.get(j))
                .getPathComponent(
                        ((TreePath) printPaths.get(j)).getPathCount() - 3)
                .toString(), 432, g, 42, Font.BOLD);
        g = drawCenteredString("File Name Printed: "
                + ((TreePath) printPaths.get(j)).getLastPathComponent()
                        .toString(), 540, g, 14, Font.BOLD);
        g = drawCenteredString("File Location: "
                + ((FileNode) ((TreePath) printPaths.get(j))
                        .getLastPathComponent()).getFile()
                        .getAbsolutePath(), 648, g, 12, Font.PLAIN);
    }


    if (summ) {
        int lineCount;
        lineCount = 0;
        int lineSpacing = 14;
        int lineStart = 13 * 14;
        g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        boolean color = true;
            g = drawCenteredString(dateS, 72, g, 38, Font.BOLD);
            g = drawCenteredString("Don Stewart Daily Summary List - "
                    + (pageNum + 1) + " of " + pageTot, 120, g, 20, Font.BOLD);
            g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 10));
            g.drawString(
                    ((TreePath) printPaths.get(x-1))
                            .getPathComponent(
                                    ((TreePath) printPaths.get(x-1))
                                            .getPathCount() - 3).toString()
                            + " : "
                            + ((TreePath) printPaths.get(x-1))
                                    .getPathComponent(
                                            ((TreePath) printPaths.get(x-1))
                                                    .getPathCount() - 5)
                                    .toString(), 36, lineCount
                            * lineSpacing + lineStart);
            lineCount++;

        int k;
        for (k = x; k < printPaths.size() && lineCount <= 41; k++) {
            String type = ((TreePath) printPaths.get(k)).getPathComponent(
                    ((TreePath) printPaths.get(k)).getPathCount() - 5)
                    .toString();
            String date = ((TreePath) printPaths.get(k)).getPathComponent(
                    ((TreePath) printPaths.get(k)).getPathCount() - 3)
                    .toString();
            String typeU = ((TreePath) printPaths.get(k - 1))
                    .getPathComponent(
                            ((TreePath) printPaths.get(k)).getPathCount() - 5)
                    .toString();
            String dateU = ((TreePath) printPaths.get(k - 1))
                    .getPathComponent(
                            ((TreePath) printPaths.get(k)).getPathCount() - 3)
                    .toString();
            if (!(type == typeU) && (date == dateU)) {
                lineCount++;
                g.setColor(c1);
                g.drawString(date + " : " + type, 36, lineCount
                        * lineSpacing + lineStart);
                // lineCount++;
            }
            if (color)
                g.setColor(c1);
            else
                g.setColor(c2);
            g.drawString(((TreePath) printPaths.get(k))
                    .getLastPathComponent().toString(), 54, lineCount
                    * lineSpacing + lineStart);
            color = !color;
            lineCount++;
        }
        pageNum++;
        x = k;
    }
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Comment: You will need to show us the relative code so that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, added.

Comment: You seem to be passing a page number to the method, but it seems that you are overwriting that variable with some other value. Maybe you are printing page number 1 (Keeping in mind that in Java the first digit is usually 0)

Comment: I just stuck in some print statements to test that, and it does start at 0. Earlier I had accidentally set it to 1, but that's fixed by now. Interestingly, however, the page count goes up to 3, where it should only be going up to 1. I'm trying to find out why, as that seems like it could be causing it.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not accustomed to this library. What I could suggest is that you copy/paste the tutorial example and make sure it works as it should, then, you start adding one section at a time and see where it breaks. This should allow you to pin point the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the tutorial example worked, so I ended up copying over the `print()` method from it, then modifying it with my specific `drawString` commands. I still don't know what was wrong with what I had written, but it's all working now.